# How to set views folder destination during runtime in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I'm trying to build a `saas application` (saas here means software as a service) in laravel 5.3. I'm trying to implement the view folder destination by extending the `ViewServiceProvider`. For example I'm having two different themes for two different domains. I'm having the set of HTML code in views in different folders, something like this:

```
View
----| Theme One
--------| Navbar
--------| Sliders
--------| Tabs
--------| Parallax
--------| Iconbox
--------| template.blade.php
----| Theme Two
--------| Navbar
--------| Sliders
--------| Tabs
--------| Parallax
--------| Iconbox
--------| template.blade.php
```

Now I want to define folder structure dynamically for these domains so that it should show the modules of their respective theme. Like suppose if I want to include sub-view of Navbar I just have to write

```
@include('Navbar')
```

and it should access the respective theme Navbar folder or sub-view. To implement this I'm extending the `ViewServiceProvider` and in `config/app.php` I'm just commenting out the `ViewServiceProvider` and added the `WebViewServiceProvider` which I made, it is not setting the destination, here is my code:

```
namespace Nitseditor\System\Providers;

use Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder;
use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider;
use Nitseditor\System\Models\Domain;

class WebViewServiceProvider  extends ViewServiceProvider
{


    /**
     *  Register View Folder
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerViewFinder()
    {

        $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {
            $paths = $app['config']['view.paths'];

            $http_req = php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? 'noetic.com' : $this->app['request']->server('HTTP_HOST');
            $domainName = explode(":", $http_req)[0];
            $domain = Domain::where('domain_name', $domainName)->first();

            if($domain)
            {
                foreach ($domain->themes as $theme)
                {
                    $paths = 'Nitseditor\System\Resources\Views\Themes\\' . $theme->theme_name;
                }
            }

            return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], array(base_path($paths)));
        });
    }
}
```

My config\app.php looks like:

```
//        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
Nitseditor\System\Providers\WebViewServiceProvider::class,
```

while executing and checking through controller I can see the destination paths of views are same as default

```
class DomainController extends Controller {

    public function checkDomain()
    {
        $app = App::make('config');
        dd($app);
    }
}
```

[image: Views directory check]

**Edit**

well I tried executing without conditional statements it happens to be same.

```
public function registerViewFinder()
{

    $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {

        $paths = 'Nitseditor\System\Resources\Views\Themes\Themeone';

        return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], array(base_path($paths)));
    });
}
```

Help me out with this.

Comment: Can you verify that you're getting into `if($domain)`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes it is. I'm setting the database connection in the same way and it is coming up properly. Also I've executed `webDatabaseServiceProvider` in boot method rather than using register method. I think if I implement in boot method it will execute, but while doing so in `webViewServiceProvider` I get error.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy well I tried executing without conditional statements and simply placing `$paths = 'Nitseditor\System\Resources\Views\Themes\Themeone';` and returning `return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], array(base_path($paths)));` it happens to be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I kept on trying to die dump the code and tried checking `$app` array. I guess when I try doing `App::make::('config')` laravel collects information from the configuration files and shows the configuration array of app in which dynamic configuration are not being displayed.

Then I simply tried checking my views:

```
return view('template');
```

It displayed the blade file/views exactly what I required, well it might help someone. Don't panic with

```
$app = App::make('config');
dd($app);
```

Cheers!!